# How to correct "class never used?

Tags: java, android

I got this code from the internet. I get the message `class note Adapter is never used, method onCreate View Holder is never used`. And all methods and classes show the same message. What is the problem?

```
public class notesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<
        notesAdapter.MyViewHolder>{
```

Comment: Delete this class.

Comment: you have code which you don't use .... so it smart computer tells you that you can delete them and program still will work. but don't delete them if you have in plan use them in future.

Comment: It seems self-evident: you defined a class, named noteAdapter, that is not used.  Are you intending to write the code that uses it?  Then ignore the annoying message.  If you're not so intending, then why have you implemented the class?  Are you confused about how it should get used?

Comment: Never copy code from the internet that you don't understand.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java interface methods never used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28727594/java-interface-methods-never-used)